# C++ - Vector will only push_back the last digit of number

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, push-back

When I try to use the 'a' option and choose 12, the vector will only add 2:

```
num_vec's elements: 2 9 2 3 4 6 3 9 4 3 2 3 4 2 3 


=====Menu=====
P - Print Numbers
A - Add a number
M - Display the mean of numbers
S - Display the smallest number
L - Display the largest number
Q - Quit the Program
Enter a choice: a   
Enter number you'd like to add to num_vec: 12

num_vec's elements: 2 9 2 3 4 6 3 9 4 3 2 3 4 2 3 2
```

Code:

```
int main(){
        std::vector<int> num_vec{8,6,4,3,2,7,9,6,2,3,8,3,2,4};
        char choice;

    do{

    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=====Menu=====" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P - Print Numbers" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A - Add a number" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "M - Display the mean of numbers" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "S - Display the smallest number" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "L - Display the largest number" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Q - Quit the Program" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Enter a choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;


    else if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
            int num;
            std::cout << "Enter number you'd like to add to num_vec: ";
            std::cin >> num;

            num_vec.push_back(num);

     }
```

Any help appreciated, head scratcher for me but should be simple. Also, please no comments that don't prove useful, like that majority so far.
Typical stack overflow ego move.

Comment: Please post [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your code is truncated, the problem is impossible to reproduce, and the only immediately concerning thing in the top part is that you do `cin >> choice` where `choice` is a char, that won't skip whitespaces before reading a command, like you probably want.

Comment: change `std::cout << num_vec.at(i) ` -> `std::cout << i`   `i` is the value in the vector not the index.

Comment: `auto i:num_vec` i is an element value, not an element index.

Comment: The bug is in your call to `std::ignore`.  Creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have helped you find that.

Comment: Apparently you didn’t notice that even the original printout was not the same as your original vector

Comment: A **debugger** is a wonderful tool.  You should use it, this is an excellent example to use.  Please post your debugging results, as text. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You can reduce the comparisons by half, by converting to all upper case or all lower case before comparing.  See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Comment: IMHO, menu selection processing is best handled by the `switch/case` statements.  It also provides `default` for the error cases.  Much clearer to read than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Thomas you're right, will have to revisit.

Answer (score 3):

Have you noticed that your `num_vec` was:

```
{8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 9, 6, 2, 3, 8, 3, 2, 4}
```

But it prints: `2 9 2 3 4 6 3 9 4 3 2 3 4 2 3`

What happened was when you are doing:

```
for (auto i : num_vec)
{
    std::cout << num_vec.at(i) << " ";
}
```

Your `i` was already the number in your vector, not the index. And if you expand your loop out, it would basically be:

```
std::cout << num_vec.at(num_vec.at(0)) << " ";
std::cout << num_vec.at(num_vec.at(1)) << " ";
std::cout << num_vec.at(num_vec.at(2)) << " ";
  ⋮
```

Or in your case, it would be:

```
std::cout << num_vec.at(8) << " ";
std::cout << num_vec.at(6) << " ";
std::cout << num_vec.at(4) << " ";
  ⋮
```

It's lucky you didn't even hit out of range exceptions. Instead, it should be:

```
for (auto i : num_vec)
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! Especially for not putting me down. I see multiple answers across the site where the commentor is talking down to the person who asked the question.